# Flat Earth experiment, but with gyroscope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, earth, gyroscopes

A man conducted "an experiment" (quotes really, really necessary) to prove that earth is flat. [Here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nNUEU8gnf4). He used a spirit level, set it up before takeoff and expected the level to be tilted after landing, becase since the world is round, the destination would be tilted in relation to origin. Well that failed, because gravity works differently than he anticipated.

I'm fairly sure I know the answer, but... What would happen if he had used a gyroscope instead? Wouldn't that work? Wouldn't gyroscope be tilted in relation to Earth's surface after landing?

Comment: yes it would. Although they tend to drift a bit over time anyway in practice.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: @JMLCarter This is an answer, I think.

Answer (score 4):

yes it would. Although they tend to drift a bit over time anyway in practice.

Comment: Especially a ring laser gyroscope or a fiber optic gyroscope. They have basically zero drift compared to mechanical ones, and they now equip all commercial planes.